# How to prevent logger from writing to stderr?

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I have a function to setup a logger.

---

```
def setup_logger(logger_name, log_file=None, stream=None, level=logging.DEBUG):
    '''
    Setup a Logger
    '''
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.handlers = []

    formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
                                  datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    if log_file:
        fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(log_file, mode='w')
        fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
        fileHandler.setLevel(level)
        logger.addHandler(fileHandler)

    if stream:
        streamHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
        streamHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
        streamHandler.setLevel(level)
        logger.addHandler(streamHandler)

    return logger
```

---

Using above, say I define the logger with following commands,

```
my_logger = setup_logger('my_logger', '/tmp/my_logger.log')
my_logger.info('This should not appear on stderr')
```

Then the output should only go to the log file, and not the stdout or stderr. However, I always get the output on stderr as well, which messes with a `progressbar` that I intend to use to track progress of another task. Any idea how I could get it to not write output to the stderr?

I am using python 3.7.3.

Thank you.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Performing those steps sends the log only to the file for me.

Comment: Any idea what might be other factors causing such behaviour?